# Batch file to login Linux sever using PUTTY

Tags: batch-file

Would like to create a batch file to connect linux server using PUTTY using port number and also without port number. Please let me know the code for it to connect the server by clicking the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Read: [Putty's manual](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-startssh) and find Answer A.6.5

You can load Putty session, provide username, password, port and lot of other options. It is well described in docs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
putty [-P port] user@machine
```